# How to make sure that both file upload and adding to database are successful?

Tags: php, upload, save

I am currently uploading a set of files via the web browser to a PHP script. The PHP script will then save the files to a local directory and store the filename in the database using PDO. I am able to do both successfully. However, I am worried about the potential of one of these processes failing and the other one succeeding.

Depending which of these two operations I do first, I end up in a bad situation:

**Method 1:**

I first create the database entry. It is successful. I then proceed with attempting to save the file, but the file fails to save. In this scenario I end up with a broken link.

Proposed solution: On failure to save I issue a second command to delete the database entry and hope it works.

**Method 2:**

I first save the file. It is successful. I then proceed with attempting to create a database entry for it, but the entry fails. In this scenario I end up with orphan files on my system that the database knows nothing about.

Proposed solution: On failure to write to the database, I issue a command to unlink the file and hope it works.

Am I on the right track with either of these options? Would one of these two methods be less error-prone or more efficient than the other? Is there another way to go about this that I have not thought of?

Answer (score -1):

Out ot curiosity, why would it fail?

However, the second method is safer: It is way simplier and faster to unlink a file you already know than to make a database request to delete the filename from it.
So the scenario would go like this (in pseudo PHP)

```
$file = 'path/to/file.pdf';
$destination = '/path/to/upload/dir';

if(move_uploaded_file($file, $destination) {
    echo 'Success';
} 
else {
    unlink($file);
}
```

As you can see, this is pretty straight forward, I hope this helps

Comment: Except that I should be checking for the success of the database entry, not whether the file was saved or not.

Comment: And again, why would it fail? If you're still in development mode, comment the part where the file is uploaded, and try with some fixed value so you'll be sure there won't be file lost in your server

Comment: One should never assume that things will always succeed. If, for example, the database server had crashed or became corrupted, that would be a source of failure.

Comment: Then, set your fields as 'required' in your database. This way, there will be an error if something fails to be saved

Comment: if you're so worried it fails, why not develop unit tests ?

Comment: Nowhere this code is straightforward. Rather, it makes no sense. It only deletes a file that PHP will delete automatically in either scenario.